# Php session display 2 bootstrap alerts instead one using IF condition

Tags: php, alert, session-variables

I have a page that call "**plans.php**" and a page that call "**register.php**". In "**plans.php**" page i have the code below:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['quarterly'];
$_SESSION['annual'];
?>


**Quarterly submit button** 

<form method="post" action="register.php" >

<input type="hidden" name="quarterly" value="">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="register.php" name="quarterly" value="Quarterly Plan" />
</form>

**Anual submit button**

<form method="post" action="register.php" >

<input type="hidden" name="annual" value="">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="register.php" name="annual" value="Annual Plan" />
</form>
```

And in "**register.php**" page i have the code below:

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

   if (isset($_SESSION['quarterly'])) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You selected Quarterly Plan - <a href="plans.php">CHANGE</a></div>';
}

   if (isset($_SESSION['annual'])) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You selected Annual Plan - <a href="plans.php">CHANGE</a></div>';
}

?>
```

When user click on quarterly or annual submit button in **plans.php** page, the **register.php** page display 2 Bootstrap alerts instead one alert related with user click and, in this same page, when user refresh **register.php** page, both of alerts continue appear.

I've also tried inserting the code below to see if terminating one of the sessions only shows one alert instead of two but no success:

```html
<?php

   if (isset($_SESSION['quarterly'])) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You selected Quarterly plan - <a href="plans.php">CHANGE</a></div>';
   session_unset('annual');
}

   if (isset($_SESSION['annual'])) {
   echo '<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">You selected Annual plan - <a href="plans.php">CHANGE</a></div>';
   session_unset('annual');
}

?>
```

How can i show just one alert without this alert disappear when the same page were refreshed?

Comment: you are submitting value using `POST` then why are you not checking with `$_POST` rather than `$_SESSION`

Comment: Use `else if` for another condition like `elseif (isset($_SESSION['annual']))`

Comment: Since, SESSION is set on plans.php, both condition on post request will be true. I think you don't need to use session in this case. You can $_POST.

Comment: Thanks for all. So, when i put $_POST everything works fine but if for some reason an user refresh this same page, both of alerts disappears. I think in this case the variable value lost when page refresh and because of this, i'm trying to use $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your code.... Try something like that.

Make it simple.

plans.php

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" >
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" value="Quarterly Plan" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="register.php" >
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" value="Annual Plan" />
</form>
```

register.php

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['plan']  = $_POST['submit'] ;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['plan'])){
   echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You selected '.$_SESSION['plan'].' - <a href="plans.php">CHANGE</a></div>';
}else{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">You don\'t have any plan, Please - <a href="plans.php">Select</a></div>';
}
```

Good programmer always avoid to use much `If_Else`, `Loops`, and  `unnecessary code`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting those `$_SESSION` values, so your session will contain them. The solution is to check which of those `$_POST` is containing via `isset`. If you want to store this into the session, then you can override the value in `$_SESSION` for the one which was posted and remove the other.